# Counting occurrence of a variable without taking account duplicates

Tags: r, count, duplicates, conditional-statements, find-occurrences

I have a big data frame, called data with 1 004 490 obs, and I want to analyse the success of a treatment.

```
ID             POSITIONS             TREATMENT
1              0                     A
1              1                     A
1              2                     B
2              0                     C
2              1                     D
3              0                     B
3              1                     B
3              2                     C
3              3                     A
3              4                     A
3              5                     B
```

So firstly, I want to count the number of time that one treatment is applicated to a patient (ID), but one treatment can be given several times to an iD. So, do I need to first delete all the duplicates and after count or there is a function that don't take into account all the duplicates.

```
What I want to have :  
A : 2
B : 2
C : 2
D : 1
```

Then, I want to know how many time the treatment was given at the last position, but the last position is always different according to the ID.

```
What I want to have :  
A : 0
B : 2 (for ID = 1 and 3)
C : 0
D : 1 (for ID = 1)
```

Thanks for your help, I am a new user of R !

Comment: Try `colSums(table(unique(df1[-2])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R, we can do,

```
merge(aggregate(ID ~ TREATMENT, df, FUN = function(i) length(unique(i))), 
      aggregate(ID ~ TREATMENT, df[!duplicated(df$ID, fromLast = TRUE),], toString), 
      by = 'TREATMENT', all = TRUE)
```

Which gives,

> ```
>   TREATMENT ID.x ID.y
> 1         A    2 <NA>
> 2         B    2 1, 3
> 3         C    2 <NA>
> 4         D    1    2
> ```

Comment: Thanks you a lot, it works ! Any idea for the second question? :)

Comment: Both questions are addressed. You mean you want the count? (0, 2, 0, 1)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach, where we get the `distinct` rows based on 'ID', 'TREATMENT' and get the `count` of 'TREATMENT'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    distinct(ID, TREATMENT) %>%
    count(TREATMENT)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# TREATMENT     n
#      <chr> <int>
#1         A     2
#2         B     2
#3         C     2
#4         D     1
```

and for second output, after grouping by 'ID', `slice` the last row (`n()`), create a column 'ind' and `fill` that with 0 for all missing combinations of 'TREATMENT' with `complete`, then get the `sum` of 'ind' after grouping by 'TREATMENT'

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   slice(n()) %>%
   mutate(ind = 1) %>% 
   complete(TREATMENT = unique(df1$TREATMENT), fill = list(ind=0)) %>% 
   group_by(TREATMENT) %>%
   summarise(n = sum(ind))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  TREATMENT     n
#      <chr> <dbl>
#1         A     0
#2         B     2
#3         C     0
#4         D     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), POSITIONS = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L
 ), TREATMENT = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "B", "C", "A", 
 "A", "B")), .Names = c("ID", "POSITIONS", "TREATMENT"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: It does not work, sorry ... But by a loop it is possible or not  ?

Comment: @AnnaCarrere  Based on the example you showed, it is working for me